# Parse error: syntax error T_VARIABLE

Tags: php, mysql-real-escape-string

Following is the code:

```
class Db{
    protected static $connection;
    public function connect(){
        if (!isset(self::$connection)) {
            $config = parse_ini_file('../config.ini');
            self::$connection = new mysqli('localhost',$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);
        }
        if (self::$connection === false) {
            die("Error in database connection. Please contact network administrator.");
            return false;
        }
        return self::$connection;
    }
    public function quote($value){
        $connection = $this -> connect();
        return "'".$connection -> real_escape_string(string $value)."'";
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error in the **quote** function:
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$value' (T_VARIABLE) in D:\xampp\htdocs\fizzy\submit.php on line 48**

Comment: Is `$value` an array? Why are you trying to cast it as a `string` -> `string $value`?

Comment: without casting, I get the following warning:
Warning: mysqli::real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\xampp\htdocs\fizzy\submit.php on line 48

Comment: Sorry, error was in function calls and not the function definition. Mark closed :) Thanks for help anyways

Answer (score 0):

Might be there is no value in $value. So you can do like this:

```
public function quote($value = ""){
```

OR

```
public function quote($value){
        if(isset($value) && $value != "") {
           $connection = $this -> connect();
           return "'".$connection -> real_escape_string(string ($value))."'";
       } else {
           return false;
       }
    }
```

Comment: $value takes input from form.

Answer (score 0):

Change `string $value` to `(string) $value`

Comment: Tried. Raises notice for conversion from _array_ to _string_.

Answer (score 0):

remove `string`

```
public function quote($value){
    $connection = $this -> connect();
    return "'".$connection -> real_escape_string($value)."'";
                                                 ^
}
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli::real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\xampp\htdocs\fizzy\submit.php on line 48

Comment: `print_r($value);` see what is there inside that. I think according to error, its `array`.

Comment: Yeah it gives an array

Comment: @ShreeshKatyayan How can u convert array to string. It will not work. Use `implode()`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at last code line

```
return "'".$connection -> real_escape_string(string $value)."'";
```

Here parameter passed to function is `(string $value)`.As you are type casting `$value`,it should be `((string)$value)`.